# Converting then diffing two dates from different tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Could someone suggest the best way to diff two dates from different tables (currently stored as `varchar` in the format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` so they may need to be converted first?)

I'm attempted the below with no luck:

```
SELECT a.[Name], 
       a.[App], 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), a.[Creation Date], 103),
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), b.[Creation Date 2], 103)
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.[Name] = b.[Name] 
             AND DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), a.[Creation Date], 103),
                               CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), b.[Creation Date 2], 103)) < 1
```

The inner join is used as I'm matching up 'Name' in tables a and b

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Comment: `Could someone suggest the best way to ....` you are already doing it.

Comment: I get the error message "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: @user3459898 . . . Then your dates aren't really in that format and you should learn to store dates using the proper database types.  Otherwise,  you get problems like this.

Comment: @Gordon - we do not know that the user is responsible for the way the storage has been defined.  However the first part of your comment is spot-on, in my opinion

Comment: Creation Date and Creation Date 2 are varchar(1000) - I thought the whole point of the conversion was to put it into a consistent date format... that's why I don't understand the error I get

Comment: Shouldn't the comparator be > 1?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012. Unless I change CONVERT(VARCHAR to CONVERT(Datetime

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
SELECT a.[Name], 
       a.[App], 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), a.[Creation Date], 103),
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), b.[Creation Date 2], 103)
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
ON a.[Name]=b.[Name] 
AND DATEDIFF(day,CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), a.[Creation Date], 103),
                 CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), b.[Creation Date 2], 103)) > 1
AND ISDATE([a.Creation Date])=1
AND ISDATE([b.Creation Date 2])=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert them from `VARCHAR` to a `DATETIME2(3)` so that they're treated as a datetime datatype instead of a string!

So what you're using is converting them from `varchar` to `varchar(24)` - rather pointless....

Use this instead:

```
SELECT 
   a.[Name], 
   a.[App], 
   CONVERT(DATETIME2(3), a.[Creation Date], 103),
   CONVERT(DATETIME2(3), b.[Creation Date 2], 103)
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.[Name] = b.[Name] 
             AND DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(DATETIME2(3), a.[Creation Date], 103),
                               CONVERT(DATETIME2(3), b.[Creation Date 2], 103)) < 1
```

And the **best solution** would be to store those dates.... as dates in your table! Stop using strings for everything - if it looks like a date, quacks like a date, smells like a date - it's a DATE and should be stored as such!